# Django - fill createview input from url <pk>

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to autofill a hidden input of my Createview.

**My url pattern:**

```
url(r'^user/add/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='user-create'),
```

**My view:**

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserMeta
    fields = [
        'auth', # This is the hidden input that I want to autofill
        'email',
        'city',
    ]
    template_name = 'forms/user_create.html'
```

**The problem**

I want to autofill the 'auth' charfield with the `<pk>` in my url, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) from the [`FormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin):

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserMeta
    fields = [
        'auth', # This is the hidden input that I want to autofill
        'email',
        'city',
    ]
    template_name = 'forms/user_create.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"auth": self.kwargs.get("pk")}
```